# RavenDB static index, query from list of referenced documents

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb

I have following domain:

```cs
class Product
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    List<CreatorInfo> Authors { get; set; }
}

class CreatorInfo
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string GuestName { get; set; }
    UserReference Person { get; set; }
}

class UserReference
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class UserReference
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I need to build an index, in which I can query **products** by product title, creator guestName and user firstName and lastName. Is that possible with single query?